# To/at/on my address

Tags: prepositions

Which of the following choices would be suitable in the blank given below

> Please make it a point to send your letter___________ .

1. On my address
2. To my address
3. At my address

I think **to my address** is correct because **send** take **to** after it.
But I am confused.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Interestingly, you refer to **two choices**, a phrase used frequently by native English speakers when talking about **a choice** - that's to say, the choosing between two options. Might be clearer for you to write **of the following three options**.

Answer (score 1):

‘on’ implies some sort of contact.

‘to’ implies movement toward.

‘at’ implies location of.

Since you used the word ‘send’ it goes with ‘to’ naturally.  The movement of sending something matches the movement toward the address.